# Anonymous structs issues in union

Tags: gcc, struct, union

I have something like this:

```
union MyBBox3D
{
    struct
    {
        float  m_fBox[6]; 
        float  m_fCenter[3];
        float  m_fDiagonalLen;
        float  m_fNormalizeFactor;
        float  m_fScaling[3];
    };
    struct
    {
        float  m_fMin[3];
        float  m_fMax[3];
        float  m_fCenter[3]; 
        float  m_fDiagonalLen;
        float  m_fNormalizeFactor;
        float  m_fScaling[3];
    };
    struct
    {
        float  m_fMinX, m_fMinY, m_fMinZ;
        float  m_fMaxX, m_fMaxY, m_fMaxZ;
        float  m_fCenterX, m_fCenterY, m_fCenterZ;
        float  m_fDiagonalLen;
        float  m_fNormalizeFactor;
        float  m_fScalingX, m_fScalingY, m_fScalingZ;
    };
};
```

It compiles well with vs2008 and intel compiler 12.0, but cant be compiled with gcc4.6.3, it gives the following errors:

```
In file included from Mesh/MyMeshTool.cpp:17:0:
Mesh/MyMeshTool.h:68:28: error: declaration of ‘float                   nsMeshLib::MyBBox3D::<anonymous struct>::m_fCenter [3]’
Mesh/MyMeshTool.h:59:28: error: conflicts with previous declaration ‘float nsMeshLib::MyBBox3D::<anonymous struct>::m_fCenter [3]’
Mesh/MyMeshTool.h:69:17: error: declaration of ‘float nsMeshLib::MyBBox3D::<anonymous struct>::m_fDiagonalLen’
Mesh/MyMeshTool.h:60:17: error: conflicts with previous declaration ‘float nsMeshLib::MyBBox3D::<anonymous struct>::m_fDiagonalLen’
Mesh/MyMeshTool.h:70:20: error: declaration of ‘float nsMeshLib::MyBBox3D::<anonymous struct>::m_fNormalizeFactor’
Mesh/MyMeshTool.h:61:20: error: conflicts with previous declaration ‘float nsMeshLib::MyBBox3D::<anonymous struct>::m_fNormalizeFactor’
Mesh/MyMeshTool.h:71:32: error: declaration of ‘float nsMeshLib::MyBBox3D::<anonymous struct>::m_fScaling [3]’
Mesh/MyMeshTool.h:62:32: error: conflicts with previous declaration ‘float nsMeshLib::MyBBox3D::<anonymous struct>::m_fScaling [3]’
Mesh/MyMeshTool.h:78:17: error: declaration of ‘float nsMeshLib::MyBBox3D::<anonymous struct>::m_fDiagonalLen’
Mesh/MyMeshTool.h:60:17: error: conflicts with previous declaration ‘float nsMeshLib::MyBBox3D::<anonymous struct>::m_fDiagonalLen’
Mesh/MyMeshTool.h:79:20: error: declaration of ‘float nsMeshLib::MyBBox3D::<anonymous struct>::m_fNormalizeFactor’
Mesh/MyMeshTool.h:61:20: error: conflicts with previous declaration ‘float nsMeshLib::MyBBox3D::<anonymous struct>::m_fNormalizeFactor’
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Should the structs not have some identifier in the union? eg `struct { ... } foo;`

Comment: So..gcc does not allow anonymous struct in unions? I add the identifier, and the errors are gone...but if I change the code like this, I will have a lot of work to do...the library has many codes like: MyBBox3D bb;bb.m_fDiagonalLen...Is there a way to let gcc allow this code to pass?

Comment: The identifier is not a name for the struct, but rather a location in the union.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in this case (where the separate structures making up the union share identifier names), you're probably better off *not* using anonymous structures.

Either that or make the names unique across the *entire* union.

Anything else is just asking for trouble :-)

Answer (score 0):

Recent GCC do accept [unamed fields](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/gcc/Unnamed-Fields.html) if you pass the `-fms-extensions` program option to `gcc` invocation, but this is an extension do the standard C99 specification.

You could also use preprocessor tricks with care, e.g.

```
union myunion {
  struct {
     int fa_u1;
     int fb_u1;
  } u1;
#define fa u1.fa_u1
#define fb u1.fb_u1
  struct {
     double fc_u2;
     char fd_u2[8];
  } u2;
#define fc u2.fc_u2
#define fd u2.fd_u2
}
```

Then you can code `x.fa` instead of `x.u1.fa_u1`  etc. Use preprocessor tricks with care and caution (remember that a `#define` has full translation unit scope). In practice you'll want the `fa`, `u1`, `fa_u1`  names to be long and unique.